# vector emplace_back usage (C++11) of containing another vector (partial vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, emplace

Has anyone known related reference for such emplace_back usage (C++11)?

```
void func(const vector <int>  &A){
    vector <vector <int> > B;
    B.emplace_back(A.cbegin() , A.cend());  // emplace vector A directly
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your real question is, but the code you have shown inserts a new vector in-place inside `B`. The new vector is initialized by calling its [constructor (4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which takes the two arguments `A.cbegin() , A.cend()`.

You can think of it as an optimized version of

```
B.push_back(std::vector<int>(A.cbegin() , A.cend()));
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that is a good hint.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better searched them on Google or [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page) before asking for any further reference.

- For `emplace_back()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back
- For `cbegin()/cend()` (since C++11): they are same with `begin()/end()` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin

Comment: Sorry about my laziness of description. Thanks, [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is not a enough hint actually. However, @daniel-frey gave a good direction, which mentions the constructor(4) in push_back.